# How do I use an custom int type with range in go?

Tags: type-conversion, go

I have

```
type DocId int

func foo(documents []String) {
    for i := range documents {
        id := DocId(i)
        ...
    }
}
```

How do I get rid of the explicit conversion line? DocIds are **meant** to be the type that indexes individual documents.

What I want is more like:

```
func foo(documents []String) {
    for id := range documents {
        ... // id gets used as the DocId that it damn well *IS*
    }
}
```

Which gives me 'invalid operation: ... (mismatched types int and DocId)' when I attempt to use the id from range as a DocId, even though DocId is an int.

Comment: No, the DocId is the type of the index into the documents array.

Comment: `id gets used as the DocId that it damn well *IS*`, except that is is not.

Comment: "DocId is an int" isn't completely true : Go is typed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only untyped constant can be automatically converted in the right type.

You can find examples where the cast is not needed like [in this thread](http://www.digipedia.pl/usenet/thread/14347/16177/), for untyped constant. From [the specs](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Operators):

> if one operand is an untyped constant and the other operand is not, the constant is converted to the type of the other operand

But here, `range` explicitly assign  iteration values to the corresponding iteration variables `(i int, T a[i])`, which makes `i` and `int`. (from spec "[For statement](http://golang.org/ref/spec#For_statements)")

For all the other case, an explicit cast is required.
The "[Conversion](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions)" section of the specs doesn't mention an "automatic" type conversion (as opposed to automatic *interface* conversion, which happens all the time: `interface{}`).

[This thread](http://osdir.com/ml/go-language-discuss/2012-07/msg00720.html) adds

```
type A int
type B int

...

var a A = 5
var b B = a    // Compiler ERROR!!!!!!
```

> Essentially, since (nearly) all types are unique, even two types with the same underlying representation and primitive operations are unassignable without a cast. [...]
>   This makes the language type-safe by forcing you to explicitly tell the compiler when you want the conversion to happen.

Comment: `range` doesn't "return" anything, it is not a function. Also, how the `error` got involved here?

Comment: @jnml I fixed the "range clause" part, with a reference to the "For Statement" spec)

Answer (score 3):

Here is another idea which you may or may not like - use a `map` since maps can have keys of custom types unlike slices.

```
type DocId int

func foo(documents map[DocId]string) {
    for id := range documents {
        // do stuff with id and documents[id]
    }
}
```